# How to set java.sql.Timestamp in prepared statement when used for TIMESTAMPDIFF calculation?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, db2, jdbctemplate

I am currently facing the following issue: 
I want to get the time difference in seconds between the current time and the given timestamp in a prepared statement.

```
public List<Foo> getFoos(String id, Timestamp ts) {
     return jdbcTemplate.query(
            "SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(2, (CURRENT TIMESTAMP - ?)) AS NEW_TIMESTAMP FROM SCHEMA.TABLE WHERE ID = ?",
            new Object[]{ts, id},
            (rs, rowNum) -> mapFooFromResultSet());
}
```

This query will fail with

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-402, SQLSTATE=42819, SQLERRMC=-, DRIVER=

-402   AN ARITHMETIC FUNCTION OR OPERATOR function-operator IS APPLIED TO CHARACTER OR DATETIME DATA
```

I am using a DB2 database and cannot switch to any other db driver.

So my question would be how do I achieve the time difference in a sql statement between the current time and a given java.sql.Timestamp value?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Should you be using a timestamp value from your table? You seem to want to calculate the difference between a timestamp parameter and "now" .  You don't need a database to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the function `TIMESTAMPDIFF` does not accept a Timestamp, but expects a String value like specified in the `string-expression` paragraph of the [docs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_timestampdiff.html). In the examples they make use of the `CAST`, `CHAR` and `TIMESTAMP` functions, so the following might solve the problem.

Instead of a Timestamp object, a corresponding String value needs to be specified in the format `YYYY-MM-DD-hh.mm.ss`:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(2, CHAR(CURRENT TIMESTAMP - TIMESTAMP(?))) AS NEW_TIMESTAMP 
FROM SCHEMA.TABLE 
WHERE ID = ?
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I tried your provided sample but ran in the same error. 
I found a solution with multiple casts as shown in the last example on the website. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Idz the `TIMESTAMPDIFF` expects a `string-expression`. Look at the last example on the provided website you will see a solution.

For my example it works with the following code:

```
 "SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(2, CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - CAST(? AS TIMESTAMP) AS CHAR(22))) AS NEW_TIMESTAMP FROM SCHEMA.TABLE WHERE ID = ?"
```